# Windows CMD FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a code which will get first words from all lines of HELP's output to a variable and echo this variable. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
set a=
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('help') do (
set a=%a% %%i 
)
echo %a%
```

But it returns first word from only last line. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion in your `for` loop

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('help') do (
set a=!a! %%i 
)
echo %a%
```

Instead of using `%`'s around the `a` variable, you use `!`'s to use delayed expansion.

Comment: +1, I know it was in the OP's question, but there is no need for `"tokens=1,*"` since only the first token is being used.

Answer (score 3):

Bali C solved your problem as stated, but it looks to me like you are trying to get a list of commands found in HELP.

Some of the commands appear on multiple lines, so you get some extraneous words. Also there is a leading and trailing line beginning with "For" on an English machine that is not wanted.

Here is a short script for an English machine that will build a list of commands. The FINDSTR command will have to change for different languages.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "cmds="
for /f "eol= delims=." %%A in ('help^|findstr /bv "For"') do (
  for /f %%B in ("%%A") do set "cmds=!cmds! %%B"
)
set "cmds=%cmds:~1%"
echo %cmds%
```

**EDIT**

Ansgar Wiechers came up with a more efficient algorithm to extract just the command names at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12733642/1012053 that I believe should work with all languages. I've used his idea to simplify the code below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "cmds="
for /f %%A in ('help^|findstr /brc:"[A-Z][A-Z]*  "') do set "cmds=!cmds! %%A"
set "cmds=%cmds:~1%"
echo %cmds%
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the echo is outside the do ( ...... )

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('help') do (
echo %%i
)
```

and no need to print a, you can use directly %%i.
Another very simple example could be a batch like this saved as help1.cmd

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('help') do (
if /I "%%i" EQU "%1" echo %%j
)
```

and  you call this batch like

```
help1 MKDIR
```

to get the short help text for the MKDIR command

Comment: Tried that. And got only lines "ECHO is OFF NOW"

Comment: That will only echo all the words, it won't put it in a variable that can be used again. This has the same result as setting the variable and using it once but the OP might have other uses for it.

Comment: We don't know what is the OP's requirement. Just _echo this variable._ We don't even know if the OP wants a single string with all the text or a line by line print.