# cmd, program generating help-files

Tags: cmd

```
@echo off
md helpgen 2>nul
cd helpgen
for /F %%i in ('help') do (
  echo %%i|findstr /R "^[A-Z]*$" >nul
  if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    help %%i>%%i.txt
  ) 
)
cd ..
```

This program is supposed to make help-files for every file from the `help` command.
But... it doesn't work correctly and i have no idea why. help me please)

Comment: as a general rule "doesn't work" is rather pointless. You wouldn't be here if it DID work. We need to know HOW it doesn't work. You get bad files created? No files at all? syntax errors? This BSODs your computer?

Comment: there are unwanted files. But, if i type "echo %%i|findstr /R "^[A-Z]*$" >nul" without ">nul" program will output correct commands at the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not working because %ERRORLEVEL% is expanded at parse time and the entire parenthesized FOR block of code is parsed in one pass. You want the value of ERRORLEVEL for each iteration, but your code is getting the value of ERRORLEVEL that existed before the loop is executed.

One solution is to enable delayed expansion at the top using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`. Then within your loop use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of `%ERRORLEVEL%`. The delayed expansion will give the desired value of ERRORLEVEL at execution time of each iteration.

Type `help set` or `set /?` from the command line to get more information about delayed expansion.

But there is an easier solution that avoids variable expansion all-together. `command1 && command2` will execute command2 only if command1 was successful. There is also the `||` operator to use to execute a command if the prior command was not successful.

But the whole excercise is kind of pointless because your FINDSTR expression will not give the correct results, so your final output will still be wrong.

Ansgar Wiechers identified a search pattern that works in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12733642/1012053). The "tokens=1" is not needed because that is the default setting.

The final script can be as simple as:

```
@echo off
md helpgen 2>nul
cd helpgen
for /f %%i in ('help ^| findstr /rc:"^[A-Z][A-Z]*  "') do help %%i>%%i.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract just the commands from the output of `help` you need something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('help ^| findstr /rc:"^[A-Z][A-Z]*  "') do (
  echo %%i
)
```

The pattern `"^[A-Z][A-Z]*  "` ensures that you'll only process lines that start with a character and have at least two spaces following the first word.